# How I can do this more better using lambda?

Tags: java, java-8

I don't like section with forEach, but I wouldn't know how to do this better with lambda.

```
list1.stream().map(element -> {
    list2.forEach(item -> {
       if (element.getKey().equals(item.getKeyNextYear())) {
          element.setSummPreviosYear(item.getSumm());
          element.setCashboxCountPreviosYear(item.getCashboxCount());
          element.setCheckCountPreviosYear(item.getCheckCount());
          element.setArticleCountPreviosYear(item.getArticleCount());
       }
    });
    return element;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You're severely abusing the map operator here, and collecting to a new list seems completely useless. Is there at most one item in list2 with a given keyNextYear? Because your code is O(M*N), and it could probably be O(M + N). If there are several such items, and you really want to update the element with the last one, you should iterate backwards and stop the inner loop as soon as you found the item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot by removing the outer stream and doing the inner part with a `filter().findAny()` search. This also prevents re-setting the properties in case multiple items in list2 match the element.

```
list1.forEach(element ->
                list2.stream()
                     .filter(item -> element.getKey().equals(item.getKeyNextYear()))
                     .findAny()
                     .ifPresent(item -> {
                         element.setSummPreviosYear(item.getSumm());
                         element.setCashboxCountPreviosYear(item.getCashboxCount());
                         element.setCheckCountPreviosYear(item.getCheckCount());
                         element.setArticleCountPreviosYear(item.getArticleCount());
                     }));
```

There is no need to stream list1 and collect it into a new list, at least it isn't clear from your sample code. The original list will still contain the same elements as the new one, including the changed properties.

Comment: If there are several items with the same keyNextYear, that is not equivalent to the posted code.

Comment: I guess the reasoning here is that `key` is a key in a map and thus unique, but _if_ that's the case (big if) then looping and filtering is the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: @JBNizet True, but the first code did not take that into account either. It just called the setters again and again.

Comment: Hence my comment on the question. The OP should clarify what this code is really intended to do.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi! I just wanna update list1 objects fields from list2. list1 and list2 contains different type objects.

Comment: @MalteHartwig thaks a lot! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

To remove 'if' - statement you can use `filter` first:

```
list2.filter(item -> element.getKey().equals(item.getKeyNextYear())).forEach(...)
```

And, I think, It's better to move setters to new method